# Getting a nested element PHP HTML Simple Dom

Tags: php, html, web-scraping

I want the commented items from an external website. I cannot edit the website.

The website looks like this, i editted a lot of things out but this is the path from the body:

```
<body>
    <div class="js-standby-status tn-relative">
        <div class="tn-container serp-mobile-container">
            <div class="tn-row tn-row-sm-spacing search-page">
                <section class="span-d-9 section-main-content-SERP">
                    <div id="js-products">
                        <section class="js-results-wrapper">
                            <section>
                                <ul class="product-list main-product-list-wrapper">
                                    <li class="product-list-item  product-list-item-first standby-status">
                                        <article>
                                            <div class="sl-search-result mobile-search-result">
                                                <a class="sl-search-result-link" href="$url"></a>
                                                    <!-- Link is needed -->
                                                <div class="search-result-body">
                                                    <a class="top-item-title_wrapper">
                                                        <h2 class="search-result-name">
            Dunlop Winter Sport 5
</h2>
                                                        <span itemprop="mpn">
                                                            5452000470454
                                                        </span>
                                                    </a>
                                                    <div class="tn-row">
                                                        <div class="span-d-6">
                                                            <div class="product-description">
                                                                <ul class="search-result-desc-list">
                                                                    <li class="search-result-desc-list-item" title="205/55 R16 91H">
205/55 R16 91H
                                                                    </li>
                                                                </ul>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </article>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </section>
                        </section>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using PHP HTML Simple Dom and PHP 7.3.

I am currently using this code to get the information from the website:

```
$html = file_get_html($url);
                        if(!empty($html)){
                            $content_url = $html->find(".product-list-item", 0)->find('.sl-search-result', 0)->find('.sl-search-result-link', 0)->getAttribute('href', 0);
                            $content_naam = $html->find(".product-list-item", 0)->find('.sl-search-result', 0)->find('.sl-search-result-link')->find('.search-result-body', 0)->find('.top-item-title_wrapper', 0)->find('.search-result-name', 0)->plaintext;
                            $content_ean = $html->find(".product-list-item", 0)->find('.sl-search-result', 0)->find('.sl-search-result-link')->find('.search-result-body', 0)->find('.top-item-title_wrapper', 0)->find("span[itemprop='mpn")->plaintext;
                            $content_maat = $html->find(".product-list-item", 0)->find('.sl-search-result', 0)->find('.sl-search-result-link')->find('.search-result-body', 0)->find('.tn-row', 0)->find('span-d-6', 0)->find('.product-description')->find('.search-result-desc-list')->find('.search-result-desc-list-item')->plaintext;
                            if(!empty($content_url)){
                                if(!empty($content_naam)){
                                    if(!empty($content_ean)){
                                        if(!empty($content_maat)){
                                            echo $item . ". <a href='" . $content_url .  "'>EAN: " . $content_ean . " Product naam: " .  $content_naam ."</a><br/>";
                                        }else{
                                            echo "Content maat is empty.";
                                        }
                                    }else{
                                        echo "Content ean is empty";
                                    }
                                }else{
                                    echo "Content naam is empty";
                                }
                            }else{
                                echo "Content URL is empty";
                            }
                        }else{
                            echo "No HTML found!";
                        }
                    }
```

I get an error in the script, not on the website but in the logs of my apache2 server. See below:

```
 Uncaught Error: Call to a member function find() on null in /var/www/html/scraper/bandenNL.php:30\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/scraper/bandenNL.php on line 30
```

Do you want more information, just comment.

Comment: Hi, as I find you don't have this class in your HTML. .item-description1 which you are trying to find.

Comment: @BukhariBaBa Thanks for your comment, this was a typo which i edited.

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: @JackFleeting The link part is a url, the ean is a 13 digit numbercode and the info part is a header about 40 digits long

Comment: I don't see any of these in your sample html.

Comment: @JackFleeting Edited the question, the items i want are in the divs and the link in the a class="sl-search-result-link"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, something along these lines should get you close enough to what you are looking for:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$htmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$htmlDoc->loadXML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($htmlDoc);

$link =  $xpath->query("//a[@href]/@href");
$name = $xpath->query('//h2[@class="search-result-name"]/text()');
$mpn = $xpath->query('//span[@itemprop="mpn"]/text()');
$title_attr = $xpath->query('//li[@class="search-result-desc-list-item"]/@title');
$title = $xpath->query('//li[@class="search-result-desc-list-item"]/text()');

echo "Link: ". $link[0]->textContent . "<br>";
echo "Name: ". $name[0]->textContent . "<br>";
echo "MPN: ". $mpn[0]->textContent . "<br>";
echo "Title attribure: ". $title_attr[0]->textContent . "<br>";
echo "Title: ". $title[0]->textContent . "<br>";
```

Output:

```
Link: my.url
Name: Dunlop Winter Sport 5 
MPN: 5452000470454 
Title attribure: 205/55 R16 91H
Title: 205/55 R16 91H
```